# Another installation is already running

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to install the QFE from [KB2403277](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=32400&wa=wsignin1.0).

When I install it I get stuck with a message "Waiting for another install to complete".

I don't have an install in progress.

How can I see what it thinks is the one in progress?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens from time to time, I typically see it either when there is a broken install or an update process running. 95% of the time it is a broken installer that hasn't quit.

I would advise launching `Task Manager` and force any instances of `SETUP.EXE` or `MSIEXEC.EXE` to quit.

Hopefully this should help you!